# Make alias for shell scripts

Tags: shell, alias

I'm working my way through the [Wicked Cool Shell Scripts](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Wicked-Cool-Shell-Scripts-Systems/dp/1593270127) book. I've created a script, following the book's code, which can be found [here](https://github.com/brandonprry/wicked_cool_shell_scripts_2e/blob/master/2/formatdir). I'm trying to make an alias for this script so I can just call it from the terminal like a command. So, it can be used easily from any directory.

I've put the following code at the bottom of the script, run it and restarted the terminal, but it doesn't work.

```
alias formatdir='source ./shell_scripts/formatdir.sh'
```

I've searched online, but I haven't been able to get the programme to run just using an alias. Is this possible or am I misunderstanding what aliases do?

Thanks

Comment: Do you just want the alias `formatdir` to run that script?

Comment: You need to add the alias, not to the "formatdir.sh" script, but to one of the dotfiles that bash reads when it starts. Typically you would use `$HOME/.bashrc`

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your alias is that is uses a relative directory. So it will look for the script relative to the working directory. So, to get it to work you need to define the alias with an absolute path (why are you source by the way).

An alternative is to add the directory containing the scripts to the `$PATH` variable by placing the following in your `~/.bashrc` (for bash):

```
export PATH=~/shell_scripts:$PATH
```

Doing so, you can call `formatdir.sh` from all new terminals. Also, you don't need to create an alias for every new script.

Comment: Thanks, though I'm not quite sure where to add this to the script? I've done a few combinations with no avail. Now, I'm adding this to the end of script.

`alias formatdir='source ./shell_scripts/formatdir.sh'`

Comment: @elliot It does not go in the script (as glenn's comment above). Everything you want to do with the terminal preferably goes into `.bashrc`